# Python, check if multiple files are empty-print results to separate file

Tags: python

I have list of files for which i need to check if they're empty or not
if they are non-empty print file name and file content, else do nothing

for example: file 1.html content: a, 2.html content: b, 3.html -empty

need to create resulting file with content of both files:

output.txt:

```
1.html

a

2.html

b
```

i have this code:

```
import os


files = ["1.html", "2.html", "3.html"];

for i in range(len(files)):

 with open(files) as file:
     first = file.read(1)
     if not first:
        print('') #nothing to print
     else:
        print file #print file name
        print file.read() #print file content
```

and getting:

```
with open(files) as file:
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found
```

Comment: `with open(files[i])` or change your loop to be over `files` in the first place, e.g. `for fname in files: with open(fname) as file:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're complicating it too much, just load the file contents upfront - print it if there's something, ignore if not:

```
files = ["1.html", "2.html", "3.html"]

for filename in files:
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        contents = f.read()
        if contents:
            print(filename)
            print(contents)
```

Answer (score 1):

You render your with statement moot since you are opening the initial array, and not files[i].  The better way to handle this is:

```
files = ["1.html", "2.html", "3.html"];

for f in files:

 with open(f) as file:
     first = file.read(1)
     if not first:
        print('') #nothing to print
     else:
        print f #print file name
        print file.read() #print file content
```

Comment: it works also, for file name i'm getting `<open file '2.html', mode 'r' at 0x7f774436f660>` how to get 2.html only ?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  That says it opened file 2.html in read only at memory address ....  What's the issue?

Comment: printed file name was long and contained many lines besides name itself

Comment: You need to print(f) not print(file) to get the filename.

Answer (score 1):

```
for file in files:
    with open(file) as fin:
        if fin.read():
            print file
            print file.read()
```